# How to use CompareOperator Validator to compare value between two others values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to compare date in textbox between today N-1 and today. For example 
19/02/15, date should be between 19/02/14 and 19/02/15 (sorry, date format FR)

For greater than (year-1) is ok:

```
txtDate.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();

txtDate.CompareOperator = CompareOperator.GreaterThanEqual;
```

How can I check that not greater than today?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I tried this but not work:

```
            RangeValidator rv = new RangeValidator();
            rv.ControlToValidate = txtDate.ClientID;
            rv.Type = ValidationDataType.Date;
            rv.MinimumValue = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
            rv.MaximumValue = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
            rv.SetFocusOnError = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET you can also use a [RangeValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that checks whether the value of an input control is within a specified range of values.

As stated in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.minimumvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) please remember that if you specify `ValidationDataType.Date` for the `BaseCompareValidator.Type` property without programmatically setting the culture for the application, you should use a culture-neutral format, such as `YYYY/MM/DD`, for the `MaximumValue` and `MinimumValue` properties. Otherwise, the date may not be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Thanks I tried RangeValidator but it not work (see edit post)

Comment: Answer updated with a note regarding MinimumValue and MaximumValue. If it doesn't solve your problem please give me more details.

Comment: That still not work, I think because the textbox will accept only FR date format (dd/mm/yyyy). Even if I use: rv.MinimumValue =DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

Comment: If you need only one RangeValidator declare it via designer and set at runtime only its .MinimumValue/.MaximumValue (using Page_Load with IsPostBack = False). I try with a TextBox that accepts IT date format (dd/mm/yyyy) and everything is ok using your code to calculate minimum/maximum value.

Comment: Maybe you simply forget to add rv to your page controls; also using .ClientID instead of .ID seems not correct to me. When it's possible I usually put every controls that I need via designer to avoid these little problems.